# Question on mixing Bloodlines with Crossblooded and an archetype

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, archetype, bloodline

I'm trying to design a Dwarf Sorcerer and work around their racial -2 to Charisma. I looked into the Wildblooded [Sage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/mutated-bloodlines-paizo/sage) Bloodline to change my primary stat to Intelligence, but I was also wanted the archetype [Stone Warder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/stone-warder-sorcerer/) which has:

> Blood of the Earth
>
> Stone warders must have a bloodline with strong ties to earth and rock. A stone warder must select the deep earth, draconic (copper dragon only), elemental (earth only), orc, or shaitan bloodline.

My question is, if I also take the [Crossblooded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/crossblooded) archetype with the [Elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/elemental-bloodline/) (earth) Bloodline, is that archetype requirement met, or would my Sage Crossblooded line be invalid?

Comment: I'm open to rephrasing or clarifying.

Comment: Has the GM already allowed this combination of archetypes, making a house rule that [this FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8k8r/faq?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Magic#v5748eaic9rai) can be safely ignored?

Comment: Good catch, I wasn't paying attention to that; lets presume my GM allows it. Answer as though I didn't pick a Wildblooded option.

Comment: As written, the crossblooded cannot be combined with any published archetypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the rules about [archetypes stacking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes/):

> A character can take more than one archetype (sometimes called “stacking” archetypes) and garner additional alternate class features, but none of the alternate class features can replace or alter the same class feature from the base class as another alternate class feature

So you can't, by RAW, take both the Stone Warder and Crossblooded archetype since the two archetype modify the Bloodline Bonus Feat class feature. Of course you can still houserule this combination of archetypes without any problem.

Considering how they should interact, the Blood of the Earth ability doesn't explicitly forbid a stone warder from selecting a bloodline that is not in this list as long as he also selects one in this list. It seems reasonable to think you need only one from this list, but as you are already on the houserule domain the best is still to ask your DM.

Comment: Good catch, I wasn't paying attention to that; lets presume my GM allows it.

Comment: [This FAQ item](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8fo1/faq?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Players-Guide#v5748eaic9thg) might be relevant to your answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, since the Stone Warder does not actually replace the bloodline class feature (it only restricts your options), you could take the Wildblooded archetype.  However, it's been stated in a FAQ that Crossblooded and Wildblooded do not stack (by RAW-- your GM can of course override this).

Comment: @AnneAunyme the SRD is a wiki, it could not be there in the future. The FAQ link is an official source.